# XITS font not found

Tags: xetex

I am running a recently updated TeX Live 2011 on a Mac (OS X 10.7 Lion).  I wanted to use the XITS fonts, but the following file generates errors when processed with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{XITS} 
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
Text $x+y=\sqrt{z}$
\end{document}
```

I'm including the relevant (I think) output below.  Any ideas what is going on?

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm XITS
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation X for XITS.
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input XITS
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf XITS
! I can't find file `XITS'.
```

Comment: You need to be running xelatex, not latex. Also, you need to download and install The XITS open type fonts.

Comment: @nathan-grigg: The error above was generated by xelatex.  However, I did not realize that I needed to download the fonts -- I thought what came with TeXLive 2011 was sufficient.  Ire the fonts that I need in the zipfile from the XITS download site [link](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math/downloads)?

Comment: I took a look at what is installed on my system by the xits package (cat version 1.103) and it includes a number of OTF files (such as xits-regular.otf, xits-math.otf, etc).  I'm guessing this means the fonts are installed.  Is there something else I need to install?

Comment: Yes, you need that and put it into `/Library/Fonts` (or wherever regular Mac fonts are installed in Lion) (I'm still using 10.6).

Comment: it's a shame xelatex would not follow the same convention as say emacs..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fonts bundled with TeXLive are not usually made available to system, font services and XeTeX can’t locate fonts in TeX tree by font name (LuaTeX based packages does, though). So you need to either install TeX fonts system wide (check [TeXLive documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-350003.4.4), though not sure with works for Mac), or access fonts by file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{XITS}
[    Extension = .otf,
   UprightFont = *-Regular,
      BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[    Extension = .otf,
      BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
]

\begin{document}
Text $x+y=\sqrt{z}$ \boldmath $x+y=\sqrt{z}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: on Linux one can define a local config file `.fonts.conf` in which additional directories can be defined, e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype/`. Such directories will then be searched by `fontconfig`

Comment: Thanks Khaled, that worked without installing the fonts (and using the document you suggested above).  Also, on re-reading your user guide (that comes with XITS) you mention that you need to do this.  In the end I installed the fonts by following the procedure here [link](http://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2010-August/044926.html) due to Herbert Schulz.

Comment: The "you need to access it by file name" did the trick for me! Many thanks!

Comment: Why is it the case that "Fonts bundled with TeXLive are not usually made available to system"? Is there some policy statement or reason given?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: that is the way things are done now, “why” is a question to TeX Live developers.

Comment: I can't see any math symbols in the XITS and XITS Maths fonts when I look at them with Font Book on mac. is it normal ?

Comment: This used to work for me (on MikTeX), but now I see that the file names of the math-versions have changed from `xits-math.otf` and `xits-mathbold.otf` to `XITSMath-Regular.otf` and `XITSMath-Bold.otf`, both in MikTeX and in CTAN, so the code needs to be updated.
(Also the main font now uses a lot of upper case in the file names. This is not a problem on Windows, but I guess it matters on Linux.)